# Adding Day to Date

Tags: javascript

I have an example below of code that getting the `date` and adding certain `days`.
But the result I got from `log` is like these **1507824000000**.

```
  var endDate = new Date('10/03/2017');
  var numOfDays = 10;
  console.log(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + numOfDays ));
```

Comment: That'll be a Unix timestamp. 1507824000000 is October 12, 2017 @ 4pm UTC.

Comment: As indicated in [`.setDate()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), the method returns a milliseconds value, and updates the date object it was called on. Use `console.log(endDate)` *after* calling `.setDate()` and you'll see a date.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply I get it now. I had to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to see your 10 days added, you can try the following :

```
var endDate = new Date('10/03/2017');
var numOfDays = 10;
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + numOfDays); 

var dd = endDate.getDate();
var mm = endDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = endDate.getFullYear();

var yourNewDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
console.log(yourNewDate)
```